# Creating a method to determine the larger of two numbers

Tags: java, methods

In this Assignment I have to write a Java program using command line arguments.  There is one method required:  `getMax`, which takes two integer variables as input and returns the bigger one of the two. Your main method must look like the following (except the comment).

```
  … main( String[] args)
  {   
 int num1, num2;
 num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
 num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
 System.out.println(“the bigger value of the two is : “ + getMax(num1, num2));
 }
```

You program may work like:

`java Assign5 23 67`

The bigger value of the two is 67

So far this is what I have; is this correct?

```
public class Assign5{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int num1, num2;
     num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
   System.out.println(“the bigger value of the two is : “ + getMax(num1, num2));
}
   public static int getMax(int num1, int num2) {
     int result;
     if (num1 > num2)
         result = num1;
     else
        result = num2;

   return result; 
   }
}
```

Comment: You changed your main method to take hard coded values rather than using the command line arguments as you specified at the top, otherwise it looks fine, is there any issue you are worried about?

Comment: get inspired http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Math.java#Math.max%28int%2Cint%29

Comment: how can change the main method so that is not a hard code

Comment: @pasito15 you don't have to do anything. If you leave the main method exactly the same as what was given in the assignment, it will work. Just change the name of the class to `Assign5`

Comment: I fixed it but i got 7 errors.... i posted a new code above

Comment: @Daniel I fixed it but i got 7 errors.... i posted a new code above

Comment: please someone help i fixed the code to my best n still got erros

Comment: @pasito15 what errors are you getting? Thank looks like it should work to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing methods with classes. The code you are supposed to write looks like this

```
/**
 * This this the class
 */
class NameOfSomeAssignment {

    /**
     * This is a method
     */
    public int getMax() {
         // Implement me
    }

    /**
     * This is a 'special' method, it launches your application
     */
    public static void main(String... args) {
          // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically got it right, that is, you implemented the `getMax/max` function correctly.

However, there are two problems with your solution:

- It does not take two command line arguments, as required, but instead uses two hard-coded integers instead. You should use the code which was given to you in the assignment.
- The `max` function should be placed inside the `getMax` class definition.

Generally, you should always try to compile and execute your code to see if it works as intended. This way, you would have been able to see both problems I listed.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the class should be `Assign5` not `getMax`

```
public class Assign5 {
```

Keep the main method same as provided.

And rename your `max` method to `getMax`.

After compiling your `Assign5` class test run it as follows:

```
java Assign5 23 67
```

Comment: what you mean keep the same method as provided

Comment: /** Return the max between two numbers */
public class Assign5{
   public static int getMax(int num1, int num2) {
      int result;
   if (num1 > num2)
      result = num1;
   else
      result = num2;

   return result; 
   
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int num1, num2;
     num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
     System.out.println(“the bigger value of the two is : “ + getMax(num1, num2));
   }
}

Comment: It says "Your main method must look like the following (except the comment)". I mean to say the main method after that. Just keep it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Five
{
public static void main(String args[])
{

int num1, num2;
num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
System.out.println("the bigger value of the two is : " + getMax(num1, num2));
}
public static int getMax(int a, int b) 
{
int c;
if (a > b)
c = a;
else
c = b;

return c; 
}
}
```